# How can I configure my email template to include the most recent email for a case but NOT necessarily ALL emails logged in the case?

Tags: email, case

How can I configure my email template to include the most recent email for a case but NOT all emails logged in the case?

My understanding is that {!Case.Email_Thread} just collects all of the emails in the "email" section and puts them in chronological order.

Essentially I'm looking for the equivalent of `{!Case.Last_Case_Comment}` but for emails.

The `Reply` link won't help me because it doesn't include the other stuff my template does.

Answer (score 1):

Query the EmailMessage Object

```
[Select ID From EmailMessage Where Case ID = :THECASEID ORDER BY MessageDate DESC LIMIT 1];
```

You will need to bulkify if this approach meets your needs